# Receiving a TypeError when using scipy.integrate.quad: "Can't convert complex to float"

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I am trying to integrate a function that includes a complex number.

I have tried separating the integral into real and imaginary integrals, but I receive an error for that as well.

This is the integration I am attempting to perform:

```
def H(G):
    return integrate.quad(lambda x: (np.pi*(np.exp(-x)))/(1+1j*G),0,np.inf)
scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda G: f(G),x0 = 1)
```

I continue to receive a TypeError message:

```
"Can't convert complex to float"
```

and I do not understand how to reconcile it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

fsolve deals with real-valued functions of real arguments.

Comment: Is there a way to separate the integrand into complex and real integrands? Or is the a method to solve equations including complex values?